# Redirect response for HTTP CONNECT from Proxy

Tags: https, proxy, httpresponse, http-redirect, http-response-codes

I've written a proxy that provides tunnelling for secured connections. However, the proxy tends to redirect (non-secured, HTTP GET) connections to a redirected page if the site being accessed is invalid. It does it by returning a "HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily" message. Will returning a HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily to a HTTP CONNECT also result in the same browser behaviour?
I've tried and it doesn't work as expected.
Therefore I was wondering if anyone could suggest the correct way of asking a HTTP CONNECT request to redirect to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

If the site being accessed is invalid, you probably want to do something other than a 302 redirect. Where would you redirect to? A 302 redirect should probably only be passed back to the client from the destination site itself, but in that case it would still be a valid site.

If the site the client is requesting is not accepting connections, you should probably return a 502 Bad Gateway error to the client. See:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.3

If you can actually connect to the destination site, you should return a 200 OK to the client and then whatever the destination site returns over the proxied connection.